# Is there any Key or name field (in Message.Header or else) SAME or RELATE for both received and sent mail?

Tags: email, jakarta-ee, smtp, jakarta-mail, pop3

Is there any Key or name field (in `Message.Header` or else) SAME or RELATE for both received and sent mail .

For example, `MessageId` is unique key for each message. But I want something else (Key).
I had not found any field in `Message.Header`(`Message` or `MimeMessage` or with also `MimeMessageHelper`)

I am using Java.Mail and I want to group each received and reply mail with a key. 
Anybody help me, Please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a word.

No.

There is nothing in the headers to tie one email to another. The closest you can do, is compare subjects + the Date.